# Where do I put weblogic-application.xml in my Maven 2 project?

Tags: java, maven-2, jakarta-ee, weblogic, ear

Where do I put [`weblogic-application.xml`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/programming/app_xml.html#wp1064995) in my Maven 2 project so that Maven places it in `META_INF` in the target EAR artifact?

Comment: Shouldn't it be under the project resources directory? META-INF usually contains META.INF for version info.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `weblogic-application.xml` should be packaged in the `META-INF` directory of your final EAR (next to the standard `application.xml`).

With the [Maven EAR Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/), the default location *for extra files to include in the EAR* (that you can control with the [`earSourceDirectory`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html#earSourceDirectory) parameter) is `src/main/application`. So the following would work (using the defaults):

```
myear
|-- src
|   `-- main
|       `-- application
|           `-- META-INF
|               `-- weblogic-application.xml
`-- pom.xml
```